# Azure AD B2c signout issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have asp.net mvc application and integrated with Azure B2C AD. In the same application, I am using API also. Login and Logout working fine. In application, some parts developed in angular and it uses application API. Now I have copied one of the API requests and sign out from the application. After signout, if I execute the API request then it executes. In API request cookie header having
cookie: __RequestVerificationToken
.AspNet.Cookies
ASP.NET_SessionId

How to handle such request.

Comment: you can make API's Protected and make sure you clear all the cookies while signing out from application and redirect the user to Azure AD B2C to sign out page.

Answer (score 1):

(Moving from comments to answer)

You can make API's Protected and make sure you clear all the cookies while signing out from application and redirect the user to Azure AD B2C to sign out page.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment. I already clearing all cookies and redirecting Azure AD B2C sign out page but still no luck.

Comment: Does the API's Protected